# Outlook : How to automate task

Tags: vba, outlook

I have 1000s of "Tasks" and "Appointments" created for testing purposes. They all are copied and pasted from one message that I have created manually hence it contains same values in Objects like "Start Time" & "End Time" and Status as "In Progress" ...

I would like to change these dates, start, end time & status progress to random values - (It is required to test the search criteria of our product i.e. to assure the our search logic can handle variation of different dates and option provided for search and so forth.)

I know I can automate it by using VBA. I have enabled the developer tab but how to get to go through the list, open each task, change the data in required field, save task & move on to next until done with the full list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA code for getting the tasks:
http://www.gregthatcher.com/Scripts/VBA/Outlook/GetListOfTasks.aspx
http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/get-ting-outlook-items-through-vba/

Use combination of both links provided

Courtesy goes to original authors. Just found these as first hits on google.